# Can't connect to local mongoDB install

Tags: javascript, mongodb, unix, nosql

After downloading, extracting, creating the `data/db` folder and cd-ing into where I extracted mongoDB, I tried running this command, as directed by the official mongoDB install instructions: `.bin/mongo/` but I keep getting this error:

`Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:91`

I can't find a concise explanation on the internet, though it seems to be a common problem, and the mongoDB docs aren't clear either. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: That sounds like you are just trying to run the client. Did you actually start the server?

Comment: How do you start the server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start the server before trying to connect with a client:

```
mongod
```

Or if you want to specifically point it at a db location, and log to a log file:

```
mongod --logpath /data/log/mongo.log --dbpath /data/db
```

Or something of this nature. This command will run the server in a foreground process. You can use `--fork` to daemonize it.

Comment: Sure thing. I actually think I have seen a question like this before so it must be common.

Comment: I feel like they should add this as the second step in the mongo os x quick start guide.

Comment: I am surprised there would be no mention of starting the server process

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something? Either way, it's not apparent

Comment: I see it near the bottom where they talk about how you would need to set `mongod` to startup through your own control scripts, but for testing purposes you can run an instance with `mongod --config /etc/mongod.conf`